# multiplying 2 functions that are both big O of a third

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Having an issue with a homework problem. Question asks if `f(n) = O(h(n))` and `g(n) = O(h(n))` then `f(n) * g(n) = O(h(n))` is a true statement.

I have been researching and the best answer I can come up with is that it is true but not all of the time. I can come up with examples where it is true but I am having issues coming up with a case where it is false. Can anyone give me such an example or at least direct me to a link that is relevant to my question? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DavidBrossard as far as I know, big-O questions are perfectly on-topic for SO, and in fact would be off-topic for the current wheelhouse of programmers...?

Answer (score 3):

This is not true, since `O(h(n))` could be a tight bound.

E.g.:
`f(n) = 2n ∈ O(n)` and `g(n) = 3n ∈ O(n)`. Then `f(n) ⋅ g(n) = 6n²` but this is not in `O(n)`.

But notice: Big-O is an upper bound, this means you can *find* a function `h(n)` such that this becomes true. For the example above `h(n) = n²` does the job.

To fix this you could say:
If `f(n) ∈ O(h(n))` and `g(n) ∈ O(h(n))`, then `f(n) ⋅ g(n) ∈ O(h(n)²)` holds.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was talking to someone from my class and they gave a similar example. I always find the answer to these questions are simpler than I think they are going to be.

Comment: Your are welcome. Such questions can be tricky. You have to look close to the wording and then check the edge cases.

Answer (score -2):

The statement is always true, but it can be a bit misleading. That's because big O notation doesn't speak to how tight of an upper bound it is describing. You can say silly things like for `f(n) = 1`, `f(n) = O(n^2)` if you want. It's not very helpful to do that since a constant function doesn't actually grow quadratically, but with big O notation, it's still true, since a polynomial function does indeed provide an upper bound to a constant function.

The precise upper bounds of `f(n) * g(n)` is `O(f(n)) * O(g(n))`. If you pick `h(n)` to be equal to the **fastest growing** of `O(f(n))`, `O(g(n))` and `O(f(n)) * O(g(n))`, the statements that `f(n) = O(h(n))`, `g(n) = O(h(n))` and `f(n) * g(n) = O(h(n))` are all going to be true, pretty much by definition. But you'll often see that there's are smaller functions than `h` that also bounds one or more of the functions.

If you want to avoid the loose bounds that big-O notation allows, you may want to use big-Theta (Θ) instead. If `f(n) = Θ(h(n))`, then for some `c1` and `c2`, `c1 * h(n) <= f(n) <= c2 * h(n)` for all sufficiently large values of `n`. That is, `h(n)` is both an upper and lower asymptotic bound for `f(n)`. The statement in the question is not true for big-Theta bounds (though it does work for a few trivial cases, like `f` and `g` being constant functions).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Much appreciated.